# Cross Validated swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Cross Validated t-shirt in your size
- Cross Validated die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### T-Shirt

[image: stats.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### Sticker

[image: stats.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Great! Thanks for this action.

Comment: Finally someone in real life will see where I waste my time. Hahaha (evil laugh)...

Comment: Yeah!  What Henrik said.

Comment: @Henrik: Waste? I doubt it. :)

Comment: Whoo hoo!  Swag!

Comment: You guys are awesome.  :O)

Comment: @JeffAtwood, Just out of curiosity, should we have already received the email by now?

Comment: @m.tibbits yes definitely; check your email address in your profile and/or your spam folders

Comment: It was in spam.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks again! I could not see it until now as it was in spam!

Comment: I wonder whether I filled out the form incorrectly, or whether there is just a delay in the line somewhere.

Comment: I got an email about this a month or so ago and filled out the form, but nothing's arrived yet.  How long should I wait before re-submitting the form?  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff, I just moved.  Things should be forwarding, but is it possible to change the address you're sending things to?

Comment: @m.t sure just email the address at the bottom of every page and we'll get it sorted.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to check on the status of the package?  I got the "shwag email" a few months ago, I've submitted the form twice, but nothing's come in the mail!  Thanks

Comment: @zach still working on it, very soon!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: wonderful thanks!

Comment: I am terribly jealous.

Comment: Its been a month and I haven't got mine :-(. Anyone else like me?

Comment: @sun still working on it, will go out very soon

Comment: Thanks!! You guys rock <3.

Comment: Mine's in!  Thanks SE Inc!